# Zener diode conduction

Tags: batteries, zener, charging

[image]

Why doesn't the zener diode conduct even while the battery is being charged at a higher voltage than 6.8v? I assume that to charge a battery the charging voltage has to be more than the batteries current voltage.

Comment: Has to be 6.8V PLUS a VBE drop before the BJT starts to turn on.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't charge a 6V battery at 6.8V.

Comment: @Hearth: Why not? Automobile power systems typically charge the 12V battery at 14.4V.

Comment: @DaveTweed Fair point. I was thinking of lithium cells, but 6V isn't even a sensible voltage for those anyway.

Comment: The zener **SETS** the charge voltage.

Comment: @Russell - To be a bit more precise the zener sets the maximum battery voltage, or cut off voltage. When Q1 turns on the lm317 goes to its minimum output mode (1.25V) and charging stops. The initial charging voltage is set by RV1, reduced by D5, and current limited by R4.

Comment: @Nedd To be a bit more precise .... Agh! :-). || Yes, but even though it's simple its more complex again. You know that. || The transistor turn on at Vzener + Vbe_Q1. BUT Vout is a D5 drop lower than the above so about equal to Vz. About. Q1 turns on in the Vbe = 0.5 - 0.6V region here. Adding a say 1K rom D6 anode to ground stiffens up the zener and keeps Q1 closer to rated voltage of zener. R4 is intended to drop Vout with increasing voltage but/and acts as a voltage munger - Vout drops as Iout increases and Vout has droped by 1V at 100 mA (V=IR = 0.1 x 10) so charge rate is low. **AND** :-)

Answer (score 1):

You also have the BE junction of Q1 in series with the diode, so significant current will flow through this path only when the battery voltage exceeds about 6.8 V + 0.65 V = 7.45 V.

That's a tad high for a lead-acid battery; I would normally keep it to no more than 2.4 V per cell, or 7.2 V for a 3-cell battery.